# DefineMethod with generic T

Tags: c#, cil, reflection.emit

> The type or namespace name 'T' could not be found

How can I use `T` in parameters?

```
Type[] tparams = { typeof(Expression<Func<T, object>>) };
MethodBuilder methodId = tbuilder.DefineMethod("Id", MethodAttributes.Public, typeof(IdentityPart), tparams);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a helper method as your vehicle of filling in the type parameter.  Let's assume you want T to be a class named MyVerySpecialType:

```
public static class Helper
{
    public static Type[] TypeArrayReturnerWithGeneric<T>()
    {
        return new Type[] { typeof(Expression<Func<T, object>>) };
    }
}
```

Then you can do:

```
MethodBuilder methodId = tbuilder.DefineMethod("Id", MethodAttributes.Public, typeof(IdentityPart), Helper.TypeArrayReturnerWithGeneric<MyVerySpecialType>());
```

Answer (score 2):

The code must be a part of a generic **method** or **class**:

**Method:**

```
public void Method<T>()
{
    // code snnipet
    Type[] tparams = { typeof(Expression<Func<T, object>>) };
}
```

**Class:**

```
public class Class<T>
{
    public void Method()
    { 
        // code snnipet
        Type[] tparams = { typeof(Expression<Func<T, object>>) };
    }
}
```